# How to add a progress bar in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I really need your help, I am new to ionic project. Currently working on a project. This app pulls blog post from wordpress using $http. How can I add a progress bar to tell the users that the page is loading,, instead of having blank screen? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$ionicLoading`

An overlay that can be used to indicate activity while blocking user interaction.

Loading is triggered inside controller. First we need to inject $ionicLoading in our controller as dependency. After that we need to call $ionicLoading.show() method and loading will appear. For disabling it there is $ionicLoading.hide() method.

Example:-

```
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {

   $scope.showLoading = function() {
      $ionicLoading.show({
         template: 'Loading...'
      });
   };

   $scope.hideLoading = function(){
      $ionicLoading.hide();
   };
});
```

[Read this for more information](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$httpProvider.interceptors` to track the `http` calls.

You can find factory written to show Ionic loader 
[here](https://gist.github.com/shamsher31/483b3e74f34240b83d45)

Or

You can achieve this by adding below code in your project.

Add below code in `angular.module('app',[]).run(...)`

```
        $rootScope.$on('loading:show', function () {
            $ionicLoading.show({ template: '<ion-spinner class="spinner-assertive"></ion-spinner>' })
        })

        $rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function () {
            $ionicLoading.hide()
        })
```

Add below code in `angular.module('app',[]).config(...)`

```
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show')
                return config
            },
            response: function (response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
                return response
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$ionicLoading` directive to show and hide a spinner. Here's an example. Just call the `show()` before the `$http` call and hide after the `.success()`.

```
controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
  $ionicLoading.show({
     template: '<ion-spinner icon="android"></ion-spinner>'
  });
  $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://example.com',
  })
      .success(function(){
          $ionicLoading.hide();
      });
});
```